# Magento 2 Invoice PDF contains weird character if comments are added in multiple lines while generating invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf, zend-framework, fonts

Magento by default do not display comments in pdf. So I wrote this code.

```
$commentsCollection = $source->getCommentsCollection(true);
        $internalcomments = "";
        if($commentsCollection){
            $internalcomments = "NOTES:";
        }
        if ($this->y <= 20) {
                $page = $this->newPage();
                $this->y = 800;
         }
        $page->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 7);
        $this->_setFontBold($page, 10);
        $this->y -=10;
        $page->drawText($internalcomments, 30, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $this->y -= 15;

        foreach($commentsCollection as $comm)
        {
                $textChunk = wordwrap($comm->getData('comment'), 120, "\n");
                foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
                        if ($textLine!=='') {
                                $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 30, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
                                $this->y -= 15;
                        }
                }

         }
```

I am facing a weird issue where invoice pdf contains character like empty box or empty box with cross in it only when you add comments in multiple lines (press enter) while generating invoice. If you add comments in multiple lines later on (when invoice is already generated) this issue does not occur.

[image]

I assumed the font might be the issue. So I changed the font to `DejaVuSans`. However it did not solve my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: using UTF-8 in your meta tag. it may solve this issue

Comment: @Sejal Shah I'm trying to add comments to a pdf. What file did you add this code to?

Comment: You need to override vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by changing a piece of code

```
foreach($commentsCollection as $comm)
        {
                $value = preg_replace('/<br[^>]*>/i', "\n", $comm->getData('comment'));
                foreach(explode("\n", $value) as $textLine){
                        $page->drawText(
                            trim(strip_tags($textLine)),
                            30,
                            $this->y,
                            'UTF-8'
                        );
                        $this->y -= 10;
                    }

         }
```